# What font Opera and Chrome use for "missing" characters in the font?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, opera

If the font can't display the proper character, 
Opera and Chrome display it in a totally different way of other browser (and I like it)

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/d72uy/

The #unicode div is styled with "Tahoma" font.

Firefox and IE display the div in the same way; Opera and Chrome use different font.

What font are using these browsers?

Answer (score 0):

chrome://chrome/settings/fonts

should help you figure it out. Don't know how safari does it but I guess it's something similar since it's the same engine.

Edit: Oh sorry it was opera, yea no idea there anyway and it's not the same engine then :)

Comment: Ahh you mean the fall back, sorry my bad. I do believe that is Lucida Sans Unicode

http://jsfiddle.net/J3Hrd/